# How to block a dynamic list of websites remotely?

Tags: networking, security, automation, blocking

**Situation:**

My juniors at work have discovered how to use proxy sites to browse sites that are not appropriate at workplace (facebook, youtube, etc.). They found that fact due to my own mistake, but that's not relevant.

**My research:**

I'm not a "networks" guy, so I don't even know that DNS servers can be set up to prevent this kind of thing. But I can use Google fairly well (at least, I think so). So I came to know that certain domain names will be blocked if the `hosts` file is edited.

So, I decided to edit the hosts file to map `127.0.0.1` to all the unwanted sites (FB, YT, etc.) as well as the proxy sites that my juniors might use. I googled 'proxy sites' and grabbed the links of first 100 results, and included those sites in the `hosts` file.

But this was my last day at work. I won't be back at office until after a month. So I thought it'd be better if I could keep updating the `hosts` file remotely, whenever I found them using new proxy sites (sites I didn't already list in `hosts`) to bypass the restrictions.

**Automating the `hosts` file update with Python:**

Which is why I wanted to make a python script append new site names to the `hosts` file. I knew I couldn't do it unless it ran with administrator privileges. That was when I asked [my first question](https://superuser.com/q/1259797/313811).

I managed to do that by logging into the administrator's account and testing it. It worked. But I was paranoid that they might doubt all these "new" restrictions had something to do with the python programs that I use regularly. So I turned the script into a binary using [PyInstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org), and placed that somewhere I knew no one would doubt.

**Storing the source text file online:**

So, that was part one of my problem. Next I wanted to find a source that'd let me store text files online (which only I could edit). But it had to provide an option to retrieve the text file's contents easily (most preferably through URL or API). I was going to post another question here about it. But then, I found [TextUploader](http://textuploader.com/).

So, I created an account and a text file. And the last part was to automate it, for which I decided to create a task in the admin's login itself, and enabling the "Run whether user is logged on or not" option, like I mentioned in [my previous question](https://superuser.com/q/1259852/313811).

*Conclusion:* I immediately knew I was about to do something stupid. So I asked it here.

**About Me:**

I have a very basic knowledge about networks. I know what DNS stands for and what it does at a very fundamental level. But I've never seen these things implemented practically. So most of your comments to my previous question required me to do more research through Google to actually start doing something to prevent these stuff.

Comment: Your company should have a corporate firewall.  You should put all the block entries in their so you only have to do it 1 time, and not have scripts running on all the computers.  However, we would have to know what kind of device your firewall or dns server runs on to give actual device.  Cisco routers have a language all their own as do windows dns servers as do linux dns servers and etc.

Comment: How do I put all block entries just once, if I can't know what proxy site (such as www.proxysite.com, proxy.toolur.com) they'll use next time

Comment: How are you blocking access to facebook directly?  You need to block access to a category of sites.

Comment: @uSlackr, err... by adding `127.0.0.1 www.facebook.com` to the `hosts` file. If that's not what you asked, I don't understand your question. : |

Comment: Do the juniors have admin permissions on their computers?

Comment: @harrymc, They do know the passwords. But none of them can dig this deep to unblock themselves. This is a small team of internal auditors. None of them knows much about systems or networking.

Comment: Another simple question - were they told not to do this?  And is there a policy for not subverting security controls.

Comment: @uSlackr, There is no written / oral policy prohibiting the employees or us (we're external auditors) from visiting such sites. However, most of the computers are prevented to access such sites by the firewall. And our senior himself uses proxy sites to browse unwanted sites. So nobody has explicitly told us not to do this. I'm doing this because I don't like it.

Comment: you are fighting a losing battle if Sr mgmt. doesn't support you.  However, you might take a look at DNS filtering services.  WebTitan is relatively inexpensive. Chasing this through host file editing is a never-ending battle.

Comment: After your internet connection device modem or otherwise there is or should be a firewall.  You place the block to facebook.com on this device, and not the local computers, then the rules can not be bypassed.  Add all the common proxy sites to the corporate firewall also.  Make a list a submit it to corporate IT so they can block it or not.

Comment: @cybernard, that does seem fair enough. But I was hoping approaching the IT department would be a last resort. By doing that, I'd be implying to the IT department that someone from our team (we're external auditors) is browsing such sites. This won't affect our relationship with the client. But it might affect the image of our firm. I should probably add more details to the question.

Comment: Do any of your users have administrative permissions on their computers? If so, it won't be long before the `HOSTS` file is deleted. Further, do you *really* want to take on the task of keeping up with all the edits to the HOSTS file? Did you block `m.facebook.com`? How about `157.240.2.35`? FB's other IPs? You *really* need appropriate blocking software (network-firewall based if possible) that blocks *by category*.

Comment: [How to get on Facebook even if it's blocked](https://www.techperiod.com/how-to-access-blocked-facebook-website-in-office-college-and-school/)

Answer (score 0):

If all computers are in a domain, you can use Group Policy Preferences to copy the new hosts file from a network share to which you have remote access.

Otherwise, do this :

- Store your hosts file in a network share that is globally
  available : `\\servername\share`
- Create a batch file that copy the hosts file in the share to the location you want such as
  `copy \\servername\share\hosts %windir%\system32\drivers\etc`
- Put the batch file in the [Startup folder](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/startup-folder-in-windows-8) of each computer.

This would require the remote access to just one computer to store a new
hosts file in the network share.
The new hosts file will only take effect when the computers are restarted.